# BIRT report encoding characters on server side

Tags: wordpress, encoding, birt

I am trying to resolve the following:

I have a report that retrieves text from a table. The table is in utf-8 and when I generate the report on my PC (client) all is fine. Both in the standard birtviewer and in pdf-format. However when I am generating the report on the server the € and  
 are not encoded correctly. If I use the lating code for € it does look fine on the server.

Were do I need to change a setting?

Thanks in advance,

Michel

Answer (score 0):

after trial and error I managed to solve the issue by converting the collation to utf8_general_ci. For the table and individual fields in the specific table (post_meta)